# Searching for file contents with NSFileManager

Tags: objective-c, macos, search, directory, nsfilemanager

I have a directory with a bunch of folders and text files. I want to recursively search this directory for a specific string.

Is there an efficient way to search for some text via NSFileManager without having to manually loop over each file, reading its contents, and performing the search myself?

If not, is there a way to do something similar by utilizing spotlight, or grep?

**Update:** to be clear, I want to search the file contents for specific text. So if I have 100 text files, I want to find those that contain specific text. Not in their filenames, but rather in their contents. Basically, exactly what grep gives me when I do `grep -r "some text" .`

Comment: You could index the files beforehand to aid in a full-text search.  There's database frameworks specifically built for that like Tokyo Dystopia.  If you're going for any old directories not under your control, you can use existing UNIX commands with an NSTask object.  For everything else, there's SearchKit.

Comment: You want to search the contents of the files for the string or just the directory filenames? It's a little unclear. Depending on that there are many ways it can be done, but without knowing it's anyone's guess which would be the most efficient.